# What is the correct python CDK syntax for passing environment variables to an ECS Fargate task's container?

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am trying to pass some environment variables, stored in a python dictionary, to a container running on ECS Fargate.

I am building the stack using CDK python.

Without the ENVs I would do:

```py
envs=None
container = task_definition.add_container(container_name,
    image=image,
    memory_limit_mib=memory_limit_mib,
    cpu=cpu,
    port_mappings=port_mappings,
    environment=envs,
    ...
```

If I now create the dictionary, i.e.

```py
envs=dict(name1='value1',name2='value2',...)
```

I can pass it into the above and it should work. But I can also do

```py
for n,v in envs:
    container.add_environment(name=n,value=v)
```

Note! Container is not 'called' again after that line, nor used as an argument to any fns.

Which of the above two options is correct usage?

To muddy the waters, what is `aws_events_targets.TaskEnvironmentVariable(name=...,value=...)` for?

Comment: Why do you think only one of those methods is the correct usage? It looks like both assigning `environment=emvs` directly, or later adding the environment variables with `add_environment()` are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.

There are different methods because sometimes you need to add some variables later in the code - in such case, `add_environment` function is very useful.

Everything is because a Python language doesn't allow you to create reference before assignment - in the CloudFormation template (yml or json) it is no matter where in the template (below/above) is defined a reference to another resource, so such functions are needed in the CDK.